# Difference between `CategoricalArray` constructor and `categorical` function

Tags: julia

The `CategoricalArray` constructor and the `categorical` function from [CategoricalArrays.jl](https://categoricalarrays.juliadata.org/stable/) seem to be nearly identical in behavior:

```
julia> using CategoricalArrays

julia> x = CategoricalArray(["a", "b", "c"]; ordered=true, levels=["c", "b", "a"])
3-element CategoricalArray{String,1,UInt32}:
 "a"
 "b"
 "c"

julia> y = categorical(["a", "b", "c"]; ordered=true, levels=["c", "b", "a"])
3-element CategoricalArray{String,1,UInt32}:
 "a"
 "b"
 "c"

julia> x == y
true
```

Is there any notable difference between `CategoricalArray` and `categorical`? If they're basically the same, then what's the reason for including the redundant `categorical` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`categorical` supports `compress` keyword argument as opposed to `CategoricalArray`.

Comment: Ok. Any comment on why `categorical` is a separate function? Maybe just because we wouldn't want a constructor to have a type instability?

Comment: I guess it is just shorter to type.

Comment: Yes, type-stability of the constructor is one of the reasons. The other is that `categorical` is a bit shorter to type.